# shortest path algorithm - matrix with inaccessible cells

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview. I am not sure how to do it. 
Basically I have a matrix of booleans - where 0 represents that a cell is inaccessible. Given a start and a destination cell , how do I construct a shortest path from start to destination without hopping over any inaccessible cell. You can travel in all four directions.

Thanks

Comment: Google for pathfinding algorithms. A* ("A Star") is a popular and simple one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use bread-first-search. Modulate a graph from this rectangular board.

The main idea:

```
Distance to start cell = 0

Previous cell for start = some not existed cell

Add start cell to queue

Mark start cell as visited

While queue is not empty

     Take off cell Y from queue, if cell Y equal to finish cell, exit

     Check all possible moves from it (goes Up, Down, Left, Right, except "walls")

     For every possible cell adjancent from Y
            Check that possible cell X is not visited before
                 If Yes, mark X as visited and add to queue
                 Distance to cell X = distance to cell Y + 1
                 Previous cell in shortest path to cell X = Y
```

After that, you could easily get the shortest path, moving from finish cell in previous array.

For more information - check Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Answer (score 1):

A simple Breadth First Search is enough to solve this problem. Here is a sample implementation in Python.

**Input.txt**

```
4 4
1 1 4 4
1 1 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 1 1
```

**Solution:**

```
import sys
from collections import deque
sys.stdin = open ("Input.txt", "r")
Table   = []
Queue   = deque()
Visited = set()

n, m = [int (i) for i in sys.stdin.readline().split()]
startx, starty, endx, endy = [int(i)-1 for i in sys.stdin.readline().split()]
for j in xrange(n): Table.append ([int (i) for i in sys.stdin.readline().split()])

if Table[startx][starty] == 0:
    print 0
    sys.exit(0)

def process (X, Y, Dist):
    if (X == endx and Y == endy):
        print Dist + 1
        sys.exit(0)
    if X + 1 != m and Table[X + 1][Y] and (X + 1, Y) not in Visited:
        Queue.append ((X + 1, Y, Dist + 1))
    if Y + 1 != n and Table[X][Y + 1] and (X, Y + 1) not in Visited:
        Queue.append ((X, Y + 1, Dist + 1))
    if X - 1 != -1 and Table[X - 1][Y] and (X - 1, Y) not in Visited:
        Queue.append ((X - 1, Y, Dist + 1))
    if Y - 1 != -1 and Table[X][Y - 1] and (X, Y - 1) not in Visited:
        Queue.append ((X, Y - 1, Dist + 1))

Queue.append ((startx, starty, 0))
while (len(Queue)):
    CurrentX, CurrentY, Distance = Queue.popleft()
    if ((CurrentX, CurrentY) in Visited): continue
    Visited.add ((CurrentX, CurrentY))
    process (CurrentX, CurrentY, Distance)
```

Comment: For understanding of algorithms its usually a bad idea to provide code, since person is in such temptation just to copy it without understanding

Comment: @Mysterion I agree. But, many a times, when I see the algorithms I dont understand them very much (may be because I am not a native english speaker). It always helps me to see the sample implementation to understand the algorithm better. Thats why I like Robert Sedgewick's books very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a simple flood-fill type algorithm:-

```
create array of integers equal in size to boolean array => map
set all values in map to 0
set value at (start x, end x) to 1
found path = false
step = 1

while !found path
  for each cell in map where value == step
    for each valid adjacent cell
      if cell == end position
        map [cell] = step
        found path = true
        end search
      end if
      if map [adjacent cell] == 0
        map [adjacent cell] = step + 1
      end if
    end for
  end for
end while

number of steps between start cell and end cell inclusive == step
```

You can improve the efficiency quite easily using stacks and queues. You need to put in a check for maps with no possible routes.